# How secure is BitcoinJ in production environment?

Tags: android, performance, security, bitcoin, bitcoinj

I am completely new to the Bitcoin scene. and have been researching a lot about it. I have also read the original white paper on it. I was looking into making an Andorid wallet where I could send and receive bitcoin. I successfully made that application I do have some questions though, I couldn't find these answers online.

I used [BitcoinJ](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj) to make the Android bitcoin wallet. So here goes my questions

1) Using the latest version of BitcoinJ is this library safe to use in a production enviroment?

2) What other security features can I implement to make wallets secure as possible if im going to store addresses in a NoSQL db.

3) From the [limitations](https://bitcoinj.github.io/limitations) section it says this:

> The Wallet code doesn’t scale well. All transactions that were ever relevant to the wallet are loaded into memory, all the time, and re-written every time the wallet is saved. This results in a simple on-disk format accessible to many kinds of apps, but has poor performance for heavy users. In time we’ll probably switch to a log structured wallet file format to solve this.

How likely is that to affect  a production application on a large scale?

Comment: anyone have any insight?